# How to simplify this js function that compares two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am trying to list out all the unmatched values by comparing two arrays of objects with fields.

As of now, this code was working fine with less amount of data. But when i pass a large amount of data means this code will consume more time. So, is there any possible to simplify this for loop.

Currently my output like

```
[ 'product1', 'product2' ]
[ 41 ]
```

But, I was expecting like

```
product_name: [ 'product1', 'product2' ]
product_quantity: [ 41 ]
```

```js
var newProductArray = [
  {
    "product_item_number" : 12345,
    "product_name" : "product1",
    "product_quantity" : 7,
    "product_cost" : 12
  },
  {
    "product_item_number" : 8888,
    "product_name" : "product2",
    "product_quantity" : 5,
    "product_cost" : 56
  },
  {
    "product_item_number" : 1111,
    "product_name" : "product3",
    "product_quantity" : 3,
    "product_cost" : 73
  },
  {
    "product_item_number" : 5555,
    "product_name" : "product5",
    "product_quantity" : 41,
    "product_cost" : 90
  },

]

var oldProductArray = [
  {
    "product_item_number" : 12345,
    "product_name" : "product 123",
    "product_quantity" : 7,
    "product_cost" : 12
  },
  {
    "product_item_number" : 8888,
    "product_name" : "product2 sample",
    "product_quantity" : 5,
    "product_cost" : 56
  },
  {
    "product_item_number" : 789,
    "product_name" : "product3",
    "product_quantity" : 3,
    "product_cost" : 73
  },
  {
    "product_item_number" : 5555,
    "product_name" : "product5",
    "product_quantity" : 0,
    "product_cost" : 90
  },    
]

function compareData(){
  let productNames = []
  let productsCost = []
  for (var i = 0; i < newProductArray.length; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0;  j < oldProductArray.length; j++) { 
        if (newProductArray[i].product_item_number === oldProductArray[j].product_item_number) {
            if(newProductArray[i].product_name != oldProductArray[i].product_name){
              productNames.push(newProductArray[i].product_name)
            }
            if(newProductArray[i].product_quantity != oldProductArray[i].product_quantity){
              productsCost.push(newProductArray[i].product_quantity)
            }
        }
    }
  }
  console.log(productNames)
  console.log(productsCost)
}

compareData()
```

Comment: The best way to do this would be to use the JavaScript standard set of functions for working with arrays. I don't know how familiar you are with SQL or LINQ but there are similar functions in JavaScript which you can use which are easier to wield and understand (once you get the hang of them). I would look at the functions map, filter and reduce, and also some of the new ES6 operators which can help perform array type functions such as the spread operator.

Comment: How is this result useful to you? I mean when you have this array with [41], you don't know to which product that quantity refers... And the expected output is not valid JavaScript notation (it misses braces). Also you are asking two completely different questions: (1) Code was working fine, but how can I speed it up? (2) Code is not working fine, how can I fix the wrong output format? You should limit to one question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You were using two for loops instead this can be done with by using one array map :-)

```
function compareData(){
    let productNames = []
    let productsCost = []
    newProductArray.map((newProd,index) => {
        newProd.product_item_number === oldProductArray[index].product_item_number ? 
        newProd.product_name != oldProductArray[index].product_name ?
        productNames.push(newProd.product_name) : null : null 
        newProd.product_quantity !== oldProductArray[index].product_quantity ? productsCost.push(newProd.product_quantity) : null
    })
    console.log(productNames)
    console.log(productsCost)
  }
```

Comment: Do we like nesting ternary operators in a single lambda?

Comment: @Max — that depends on how we format our ternary operators 